# What is the reason of cmake error when using freetype2 header?

Tags: compiling

I build a simple *glfw*, *glad* project on vs code successfully. My issue is. I add <freetype2/ft2build.h> header to my project and I do those commands in my project folder:

```
sudo su
cd build
cmake ..
make
```

normally that works without error.

I get error called:

```
    In file included from /home/gomi/Documents/ubuntuProject/main.c:3:
    /usr/include/freetype2/ft2build.h:39:10: fatal error: freetype/config/ftheader.h: No such file or directory
       39 | #include <freetype/config/ftheader.h>
          |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~compilation terminated.
```

I went to usr/include/freetype2 path from terminal.
If I remember correctly I seen only ft2build.h in directory no other config folder.
I downloaded freetype2 files and I copied freetype folder to this directory and I got same error. In the end of I deleted copied freetype folder. I am not sure if they were already there and I damaged freetype2.

What I should do ?

Comment: File list 18.04 https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/amd64/libfreetype6-dev/filelist .... File list 20.04 https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/amd64/libfreetype-dev/filelist

Comment: You shouldn't be using `sudo` or root for `cmake` or `make`. You only need root permission for the install part of the process. If you've already used root permission to try and build, the best thing to do would be to start over, delete the directory and redownload the source to start fresh. Alternatively, you could try running `sudo make clean` but there's no guarantee this will work.

Comment: yes you are correct @mchid, I somehow wrote it write protected when I first did. At this time I deleted content of build then rebuild it. Without becoming root now that builds. However, this strange header issue remains.

Comment: here is a similar issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34910660/fatal-error-freetype-config-ftheader-h

Answer (score 1):

As I stated, you shouldn't be running `cmake` and `make` as root but that appears to be a different issue.

As for your problem, first delete the file you added manually. Then, you can install the following package to fix the issue:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install --reinstall libfreetype6-dev
```

You can locate files like this using the `apt-file` command.

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install apt-file
sudo apt-file update
apt-file search ftheader.h
```

This will return which package contains the file you need.

**<sub>NOTE:</sub>**

<sub>On 20.04, the package that contains the file is `libfreetype-dev` however, this package is a dependency of `libfreetype6-dev` so it should all work just the same.</sub>

<sub>Also, the path shown by `apt-file` is the same one requested by `/usr/include/freetype2/ft2build.h` on line 39 with respect to the working directory of that file. So you shouldn't have to tell `cmake` where to look for this file and you shouldn't have to put a copy in `/usr/include/freetype2`</sub>

Answer (score 0):

After searching for hours. I think I found it. First, that tries to search it in wrong directory unless you tell it to cmake.

I found it on this page : https://techoverflow.net/2019/06/11/how-to-fix-ft2build-h-no-such-file-or-directory/

1. I just added to vs code's include directories `/usr/include/freetype2`
2. I put header `#include <ft2build.h>` and `FT_FREETYPE_H` just after it, to my `main.c` file.
3. I used `pkg-config --cflags freetype2` command to ensure its location `-I/usr/include/freetype2`
4. I went to `CMakeLists.txt` file then I added `include_directories (/usr/include/freetype2)` line. Final CMakeLists.txt file looks like this:

   ```
   cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.20.3)

   project(gomi)

   include_directories (/usr/include/freetype2)

   add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} glad.c main.c)

   target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} GL dl glfw)
   ```
5. My commands to re-build it:

   ```
   cd ../            # one path pack from build folder)
   rm -r build/*     # delete all files in build)
   cd build
   cmake ..
   make
   ./myprogramname   # runs
   ```

Comment: You should probably be using `find_package` and then setting `target_include_directories` with the found `FREETYPE_INCLUDE_DIRS` value, instead of hard-coding `include_directories (/usr/include/freetype2)` (that's kind of the point of `cmake` - to locate things in a system-agnostic way). See for example [Linking freetype with cmake](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23888557/4440445)

Comment: @steeldriver Thank you, I did proper modifications. I just did not use SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-O2 -std=c++11") rest of that works without any problem.